# npm ERR! while running wails dev or wails build command for age-viewer-go

Tags: go, apache-age, wails

I need to run the [age-viewer-go project](https://github.com/apache/age/tree/ageviewer_go) when I run `wails dev` or `wails build` command in the main directory it run well but only one page is shown up with start button and that button does not work.

[image: image showing age-viewer-Desktop (Go) Projects main page]

I asked a friend he told me to run `waisl dev` command in the age-viewer folder (a sub folder in the root folder (age-go)

when I tried `wails dev` command in the age-viewer folder it encountered the following error

[image: image showing error]

kindly someone help me to resolve the error

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error while running the front-end of apache-age-viewer Desktop app, Just simply install the **react-router-dom** to solve this error:

`npm install react-router-dom`

Comment: Thank you I tried and run the application successfully